# what is the new version of java cloud files jar

Tags: java, cloud, rackspace

I used java-cloudfiles-1.0.jar (of rackspace) , 
I need to know what is the new version of this jar and from where i can download it.
can you please elaborate and send the link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of java-cloudfiles is 1.10.0. You can get it by downloading it from [the Rackerlabs GitHub page](https://github.com/rackerlabs/java-cloudfiles) and [building it with ant](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/java-api-installation).

However, you should be aware that java-cloudfiles has been deprecated in favor of [jclouds](http://jclouds.apache.org/documentation/quickstart/rackspace/). More resources are also available on the [Rackspace SDKs page](http://docs.rackspace.com/sdks/guide/content/java.html). If you're already upgrading, I'd recommend changing to the newer SDK instead!